# How do I mouseover

Tags: dom

I am doing a course on DOM Event manipulation.
I am trying to make a todolist where the color of the li changes when I hover on it.
My problem is that the color changes when I click on the element and not when I hover on it. Thank you in advance.

I have the following js:

```js
var lis = document.querySelectorAll("li");

for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++){
  lis[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
    this.classList.add("selected");
  });
  lis[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
    this.classList.remove("selected");
  });

  lis[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
   this.classList.toggle("done");
  })
}
```

```css
.done {
 text-decoration: line-through;
 opacity: 0.5;

}

.selected {
 color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Todo List Demo</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="todos.css">
</head>
<body>

 <ul>
  <li>Wash cat</li>
  <li>Feed Cat</li>
  <li>Feed cat to dog</li>
 </ul>

<script type="text/javascript" src="todos.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It changes colour when I mouseover it (although why you aren't just using CSS's `:hover` I've no idea)

Comment: Your code works fine for me, are you using chrome, have Developer Tools opened and enable "Device Toolbar" (Ctrl + Shift + M) by any chance? Because if you have Developer Tools opened, it wont register the on hover

Comment: Thank you Quentin. You re right it does changes color when I mouse over in the stackoverflow snippet. but not when I open my document in chrome.

Comment: @VincentJonathan yes I have developer Tools opened

Comment: Do you have your Device Toolbar toggled on? (On the top left of developer tools, there's an icon of 2 screen, like phone and tab) If you have it on, try to turn it off.

Comment: @VincentJonathan yes that was it. Thank you!!

Comment: No problem, i guess it changes the browser behavior as if you are opening it from a mobile device when you have the Device Toolbar toggled on, hence why you can hold click and drag to scroll, and don't trigger `mouseover` since it's not possible to "hover" on a touchscreen mobile device

Answer (score 0):

Html part:

```
<ul>
   <li onmouseenter="enter(0)" onmouseout="out(0)">Milk</li>
   <li onmouseenter="enter(1)" onmouseout="out(1)">Eggs</li>
   <li onmouseenter="enter(2)" onmouseout="out(2)">Fruits</li>
</ul>
```

Js:

```
function enter(x) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('li')[x].style.color = "red"
}
function out(y) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('li')[y].style.color = "black"
}
```

By The way I just tested the code and It worked! :)